# Writing a stream into a file doesn't work propely

Tags: c#, stream, memorystream

I am making a program that transports a file in chunks over TCP. Now, Each time I transfer a file a little bit at the end doesn't seem to be written in and so if I try to transfer a picture [at the bottom right there are glitches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0qaj.png). 
Now, my first idea was that when I read, transfer and write the final chunk that is smaller that the buffer length, I write in a lot of zeroes too. So I tried to change the last buffer size accordingly. I then tried that out using a small text file that only has HELLO WORLD written in it, but when I write it in, and then open the file, it is empty.

Here is the reading and sending code where range[0] is the first part and range[1 ] is the last part:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[DATA_BUFF_SIZE];
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(file.Path))
{
    Console.WriteLine("SENT PARTS # ");
    for (int i = range[0]; i <= range[1]; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("PART " + i + ", ");

        if (i == range[1])
        {
            buffer = new byte[input.Length - input.Position];
        }

        input.Position = i * DATA_BUFF_SIZE;
        input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        netStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    }
    Console.WriteLine("LENGTH = " + input.Length);
}
```

here is the receiving and writing code:

```
int bytesReceived = 0;
int index = partRange.First;
int partNum = 0;
byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];

if (index == partRange.Last)
{
    receiveBuffer = new byte[fileToDownload.Length - index * BUFF_SIZE];
}

while ((bytesReceived = netStream.Read(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    Console.Write("INDEX:" + index + ", ");
    output.Position = index * BUFF_SIZE;
    output.Write(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length);
    index++;
    partNum++;

    if (partNum > (partRange.Last - partRange.First))
    {
        break;
    }

    if (index == partRange.Last)
    {
        receiveBuffer = new byte[fileToDownload.Length - index * BUFF_SIZE];
    }
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

What am I missing? I even printed out the buffer on client and server and it is equal.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @René Vogt Sorry, I tried using the stackoverflow code button but it messed up all of the indentation and I couldn't find how to highlight it. I'll format it better next time.

Answer (score 2):

Try `netStream.Flush();`

I suspect what's happening is the stream is getting closed before the writing finishes. Sometimes the output stream will continue to write asynchronously. You'll find this when dealing with file streams too. Using `Flush()` forces the stream to finish whatever writing operation it is doing before continuing execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
output.Write(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length);
```

Needs to be

```
output.Write(receiveBuffer, 0, bytesReceived);
```

Not every call to netStream.Read will fill receiveBuffer.

There may be other errors but that was the big one that jumped out at me.

EDIT: looks like the sending side has the same error but you don't even save the result from input.Read(

Comment: There's also little point in changing the position of both input and output streams.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain I adjust the buffer. If the length parameter is smaller than the buffer length, will it just cut off the buffer when the length is achieved?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath This seems wrong but it's a part of a multithread program so the position will not advance each time but change a lot.

Comment: @Foxman if you try to write a buffer of 1000 to an array that has only has a length of 900, you'll get an OutOfRangeException. And BTW, there's absolutely no mention of multi-threading in your post

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

---

There isn't a size limitation, the buffer is the only limitation.  Which in 4.5.1 appears to be 81920 bytes.  The physical implementation of `Stream.CopyTo` is provided [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,98ac7cf3acb04bb1) and below:

```
private void InternalCopyTo(Stream destination, int bufferSize)
{
     Contract.Requires(destination != null);
     Contract.Requires(CanRead);
     Contract.Requires(destination.CanWrite);
     Contract.Requires(bufferSize > 0);

     byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
     int read;
     while ((read = Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
          destination.Write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

---

You could make your life easier, by simply doing:

```
input.CopyTo(output);
```

This is a shortcut to quickly copy the data. Copying begins at the current position in the current stream, and does not reset the position of the destination stream after the copy operation is complete.

```
using(MemoryStream destination = new MemoryStream())
     using(FileStream source = File.Open("..."))
     {
          source.CopyTo(destination);
     }
```

You could easily make a method, with this approach:

```
public static MemoryStream GetStream(this FileStream source)
{
     using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
     {
          source.CopyTo(stream);
          return stream;
     }
}
```

You would want error handling, but as you can see this method is incredibly flexible when copying data between Streams.  Should be able to bend this approach to your specific development needs.  You can find more information on the Microsoft Developer Network about the method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: wont this work only with small streams? I am working with chunks that I transfer over TCP so I can't transfer all of the stream at once

Comment: @Foxman In 4.5.1 it had a fixed buffer size of 81920 bytes, but does have an overload for your own buffer size.  The size of data doesn't matter, implementation information here. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,98ac7cf3acb04bb1